# How to Call Database Stored Function via Fluent Nhibernate and Get IQueryable<T> as a Result

Tags: .net, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I have stored database function for calculated nearest locations:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LoadNearBusinesses
    (
        @latitude DECIMAL(25, 10),
        @longtitude DECIMAL(25, 10),
        @areaRadius DECIMAL(25, 10)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    return SELECT DISTINCT [Business].* FROM [Business] 
     LEFT JOIN [BusinessLocation] ON [BusinessLocation].Business_id = [Business].Id 
     LEFT JOIN [Location] ON [BusinessLocation].Id = [Location].Id
     WHERE 6371 * ACos(COS(@latitude* PI() / 180) * Cos([Location].Latitude * PI() / 180) * Cos(([Location].Longitude- @longtitude)* PI() / 180) + SIN(@latitude* PI() / 180) * Sin([Location].Latitude* PI() / 180)) <= @areaRadius;
```

And now I need to call this function from my code and get **IQueryable<*Business***> as a result for using it in telerik grids.

I try:

```
Session.CreateSQLQuery(
                string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LoadNearBusinesses]({0},{1},{2})",
                latitude, longitude, radius)).AddEntity(typeof(Business)).List<Business>();
```

But this is List, and when when I add additional filtration it will be executed in memory, not in database.

Have you any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an `IQueryable<Business>` using the same logic as the stored procedure. You'll need a reference to NHibernete.Linq for this to work.

```
int latitude = 1;
int longitude = 2;

var q = from business in session.Query<Business>()
        join businessLocation in session.Query<BusinessLocation>()
           on business.Id equals businessLocation.Business_Id into busBusLoc
        from subBusiness in busBusLoc.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join location in session.Query<Location>()
           on businessLocation.Id equals location.Id into busBusLocLoc
        from subBusinessLocationLocation in busBusLocLoc.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (6371 * Math.Acos(Math.Cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180) 
                    * Math.Cos(l.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) 
                    * Math.Cos((l.Longitude - longtitude) * Math.PI / 180) 
                         + Math.Sin(latitude * Math.PI / 180) 
                         * Math.Sin(location.Latitude * Math.PI / 180)))
                <= areaRadius
        select business;
```

Of course normally your ORM is going to only relate entities via an inner join, so you have to do the left joins manually here. The `where` and `select` should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but Linq to Nhibernate does not support Math.Acos, Math.Cos functions

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you can face with @SteveMallory query (which i think is the right thing to do) is that Linq to NHibernate does not support Math trigonometric functions, but it does support extending itself :).

Check this two links to solve this problem: 
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.mx/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html and 
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Test/Linq/CustomExtensionsExample.cs

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But as I understood no "traditional" ways for working with stored functions with Fluent Nhibernate